# Remove special chars from URL

Tags: php, string

I have a product database and I am displaying trying to display them as clean URLs, below is example product names:

```
PAUL MITCHELL FOAMING POMADE (150ml)
American Crew Classic Gents Pomade 85g
Tigi Catwalk Texturizing Pomade 50ml
```

What I need to do is display like below in the URL structure:

```
www.example.com/products/paul-mitchell-foaming-gel(150ml)
```

The problem I have is I want to do the following:

```
1.  Remove anything inside parentheses (and the parentheses)
2.  Remove any numbers next to g or ml e.g. 400ml, 10g etc...
```

I have been banging my head trying different string replaces but cant get it right, I would really appreciate some help.

Cheers

Comment: In your specific first case, where the units is inside the parentheses, removing the parentheses and its content will also remove the unit, can you confirm?

Comment: YesI want to remove anything in braquets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function makeFriendly($string)
{
    $string = strtolower(trim($string));
    $string = str_replace("'", '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#[^a-z\-]+#', '_', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#_{2,}#', '_', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#_-_#', '-', $string);
    return preg_replace('#(^_+|_+$)#D', '', $string);
}
```

this function helps you for cleaning url. (also cleans numbers)

Comment: why change it to lower case and then check for `A-Z` - also, instead of that last `preg_replace` you could use `trim($string, '_')`

Comment: ups. i forgot. i'd edited. John, you can also strip "ml" "gr" with str or preg replace.

Comment: Cheer Osman, few issues with it:

1.  I need to remove any char in the braquets not just numbers
2.  Also I need to leave numbers in there which are not connected to "ml" or "gr"

Cheers.

Comment: this code
<code>
$str = 'Osman Ungur (34000, Turkey)';
echo preg_replace('(\(.*\))Us', "", $str);
</code>

is stripping braquets from string. you can add this to my function. im looking for your second request.

Comment: Osman,

Lovely everything in the braquets has now removed, still problem of "ml" and "g" left, I cant do a str replace becuase it will remove any "g's" from the URL I need it to only remove "g" or "ml" when next to number.  Also need to beable to display numbers which are not next to "ml" of "g"

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```html
<?php
$url = 'http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.com';
$decodedurl= urldecode($url);
echo $decodedurl;
?
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$from = array('/\(|\)/','/\d+ml|\d+g/','/\s+/');
$to = array('','','-');

$sample = 'PAUL MITCHELL FOAMING POMADE (150ml)';
$sample = strtolower(trim(preg_replace($from,$to,$sample),'-'));
echo $sample; // prints paul-mitchell-foaming-pomade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', preg_replace("/(?:\(.*?\)|\d+\s*(?:g|ml))/", "", $input)));

// "abc (def) 50g 500 ml 3m(ghi)" --> "abc 3m"
```